# View won't save end date configuration as filter criteria

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal 7 with views 7.x-3.15 and Date 7.x-2.9

I have a date field for an "Events" content type. Events can sometimes last more than 1 day, so I have enabled an associated end date.
See in the video (linked below) that I :

1. Add the date field as a filter
2. Set the the "End date" as a relative date (now)
3. Apply the changes
   But when I re-open the filter, the settings I just applied are now associated to the start date, not the end date.
   In the video, I repeat the process a couple of times just to demonstrate that it's not doing as I'd expect.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2rAzwIHJZE

*Further detail (maybe not relevant)
I need to select events that even though their start date has passed, their end date is still in the future. I realise in the video that I've selected >= but don't worry about that - the problem is that the filter won't save my configuration.*

Has anyone else had experience of this?  Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report which must be filed on drupal.org not here on Drupal Answers. Thank you for your understanding

Comment: Is it a bug though, or am I just doing something wrong ?

Comment: Your post didn't contain any question so it's a bug report. Is it not?

Comment: Hey Leymannx,  I'm happy to accept that this is a bug, but I've edited my post so there's a clear question. I just wanted to check to see if I had done something wrong in the setup

Comment: I don't think you are doing something wrong. I think this is a bug. In the Date module or which modules provides this field. Worth checking at last, if you had any JS errors in the console.